# How NVM Command in a .service

Tags: service, discord.js, nvm

I searched around for `.service` file that start a screen and also run "nvm start"

It's for a Discord Bot to automatically start.
The problem is that when I start the `.service` file, it's immediately deactivated. It doesn't open a window or start my Discord bot. It also doesn't create any log file.
Nothing. It only says that the service was deactivated successfully.
I try that everything on my Raspberry Pi 4b with Ubuntu Server 23 (latest one)
Latest version of NPM, NVM, Node... I guess everything is on latest.
I run everything via root with a stable Wi-Fi connection.
No problems with any packages.
When I use `node .`, it works perfectly. Only when I use the nvm start does it not work.

```ini
[Unit]
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=lultwo
Environment=NODE_VERSION=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/screen -dmL LOGFILE.log -S schnurrBot /root/.nvm/nvm-exec npm start --prefix /home/lultwo/Schnurr/Public/

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I got this problem directly after starting the service file:

```
○ schnurrBot.service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/schnurrBot.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2023-09-28 20:49:31 CEST; 2s ago
   Duration: 21ms
    Process: 3613 ExecStart=/usr/bin/screen -dmL LOGFILE.log -S schnurrBot /root/.nvm/nvm-exec npm start --prefix /home/lultwo/Schnurr/Public/ (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 3614 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 42ms

Sep 28 20:49:30 RaspTwo systemd[1]: Starting schnurrBot.service...
Sep 28 20:49:31 RaspTwo systemd[1]: Started schnurrBot.service.
Sep 28 20:49:31 RaspTwo systemd[1]: schnurrBot.service: Deactivated successfully.
```